# How do you access an ace editors settings as a user?

Tags: google-chrome, github

Now from reading [here](http://usevim.com/2013/12/18/vim-editor-for-github/) and from viewing this screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/69m9u12d0696vb0/Screenshot%202013-12-13%2013.54.24.PNG) it seems that there is a way to access the ace editor menu settings (copied from source linked to above):

"You can press CTRL+, or CMD+, (depends on your OS) to access Ace’s settings menu and enable Vim mode there"

Now my problem is on both firefox and chrome ctrl+ (on linux) is mapped to make the selection larger. How do you access this, I have tried looking at [the ace website](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) and [their github page](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) and have been unable to find how to access this menu, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this and realised my stupidity at misreading the quote, C-, or ctrl+, works fine, source:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Default-Keyboard-Shortcuts